How to process "streaming response" or "chunked response" data from a streaming REST API endpoint with Blazor server-side using .NET 6.x?
With my Blazor application, I am hitting a REST API endpoint  that produces both streaming and non-streaming results, depending on the endpoint I hit. The non-streaming endpoint is just standard JSON:
{
    "key":"value",
    ...
}

Which I have no problem processing to the Blazor front-end.
However, the streaming is not standard JSON, and looks like this:
data: {
    "key":"value",
    ...
    "data_complete_token":false
}

data: {
    "key":"value",
    ...
    "data_complete_token":false
}

data: {
    "key":"value",
    ...
    "data_complete_token":false
}

...

data: {
    "last_key":"last_value",
    ...
    "data_complete_token":true
}

After many Google searches, I believe the data coming from the streaming endpont is called a "streaming response" or "chunked response".
I have done some Google searches using these parameters:
how to read data from rest api streaming response with blazor server -WebAssembly
And I seem to still get results for WebAssembly and not many for server-side. Those that are for server-side don't seem to be what I am looking for.

EDIT:
To clarify what I am doing, I am hitting a Mixtral LLM endpoint which "streams" it's responses one word at a time.

That's not a streaming or chunked response. HTTP has no streaming support, gRPC does. Even the records aren't valid JSON but something else. You just can't parse "data": {.....} as JSON. People use streaming JSON to send unindented JSON in separate lines, but individual records are still JSON. There's also a standardized application/json-seq type where indented valid JSON records are surrounded by specific separators.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. I clarified what I am doing in an edit just now. I am hitting a Mixtral LLM endpoint, which returns the data:{ ... } responses, one word at a time, like I have described.

It doesn't matter what the endpoint is, this isn't streaming JSON or even partial JSON records. The only way to handle this non-streaming, non-JSON response is to find out what the actual separators are, read the text from one separator to the next and parse it. It may be possible to surround that text with { ..} to get a valid JSON record. Or you can look for some kind of client or SDK for that endpoint

Do you really mean Mistral API? Mixtral is a specific feature in the Mistral API. Mistral uses Server-Sent-Events to push messages from the server to the client. It's an older alternative to webhooks. The client opens a long-lived connection to the server and the server writes records separated by an empty line (actually two newline characters) that have headers like event:, data: etc. Browsers can already use the EventSource class to receive SSEs, so at least you can use JavaScript

Do you want to handle the messages on the browser or server? On the browser they're already handled by EventSource. On the server you'll have to create your own EventSource equivalent

Someone's built an unofficial Mistral client by the way, that handles these SSE events internally. There are also SSE EventSource packages in NuGet like this one

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes, Mistral API. I have been looking at Server-Sent-Events, but I cannot find any good concrete examples of how to consume them with Blazor, or even plain JavaScript for that matter.

I posted the links to the Mozilla docs and examples already - here it is again. You really, really don't need to do anything more than those 2-3 lines - const evtSource=new EventSource(endpoint_url); and then handle the onmessage event. I also posted a link to a client you can use on the server side

@PanagiotisKanavos Much appreciated. I have discovered that my issue may be the LLM REST API endpoint I am hitting. Even when I have JUST EventSource(llm_rest_api_endpoint) I get an 405 (Method Not Allowed) error from the endpoint. I believe I will be looking at one of NuGet library you suggested. Thanks, again!

Indeed, the client uses POST which the browser's EventSource doesn't support.
